# Cannot upgrade from 20.04 to 22.0X

Tags: apt, upgrade, update-manager

I have run  `sudo apt update` and aside from a failure to get stuff from the R repository, no problems.  `sudo apt upgrade` runs fine.

But if I try to get the SoftwareUpdater tool to run, when I click the "upgrade" button,  it crashes.
I tried using `sudo do-release-upgrade` but it just tells me I need to run "update" first.

None of the advice on older question pages has helped.
Is there something I should try to edit/clear/reset that might help?  Am I going to be forced to start 'from scratch' with an ISO on a thumb drive?

UPDATE:
I cleared out the bad item from the sources.list file, and now the update commands run without error (and without doing anything new). I tried all the additional  `apt`  commands provided in the comments, to no avail.

then this:

```
%  sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

% sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  r-cran-foreign
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

That's all I get, and SoftwareUpdater still crashes if I try that out.

Comment: Get rid of the sources entry for R. If you get a failure in update and upgrade a version upgrade wont work either. It is like a flat tire and you try to drive anyway.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft what does `sudo apt install r-cran-foreign` say?  That will give us some insight into *why* the package does not upgrade/install such as dependency problems, etc.  **Alternatively**, consider running `sudo apt remove r-cran-foreign` which will remove R from your system if that was installed separately by another source.  And then install it again from wherever you got it *after* upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only did I have to remove R items from the sources list, I had to run `sudo apt remove r-cran-foreign`  , after which running the updater allowed me to execute `sudo apt autoremove` to completely clear out all installed `R` files.  After this last step  the OS updater ran successfully from `SoftwareUpdater` .

I'll worry about reinstalling the proper version of `R` later -- that I can deal with.